# Combo box selected index event not giving output in one click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a form in which there are two combo box and a grid,
i have written filtering code on selectedindex changed event of combo box,SuggestAppend property is set for combo box.when i type a country name eg india and press enter the selected index changed event does not fire immediately,when i click somewhere out then its fires and gives output.
  Please suggest me what to do.Thanks in advance

```
  protected void cbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCondition();
            Fillgrid();
        }

     public string GetCondition()
            {
                string Condition = "";
                if (cbEmployee.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    Condition = Condition + " And reg_no=" + cbEmployee.SelectedValue;
                }

                if (cbCountry.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    Condition = Condition + " And country='" + cbCountry.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
                }
      return Condition;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
on the grid tag

<Grid>

try the following code

    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true" 
                KeyboardNavigationSettings-AllowSubmitOnEnter="true"
                KeyboardNavigationSettings-AllowActiveRowCycle="true" 
                KeyboardNavigationSettings-CollapseDetailTableKey="LeftArrow"
                KeyboardNavigationSettings-ExpandDetailTableKey="RightArrow">

            </ClientSettings>




</Grid>
```

this will make sure you enable keyboard navigation in your grid

Comment: i am using telerik radgrid,most of these properties are not supported in telerik

Comment: actually the client settings attributes are for telerik .